# Update the value set by CompositionContainer.ComposeExportedValue in MEF

Tags: c#, .net, mef

I am using ImportingConstructor in MEF like:

```
public class ClassA : IClassA
{
    private string _message;

    public ClassA()
    {
        _message = "Message from constructor 1 of class A";
    }

    [ImportingConstructor]
    public ClassA([Import("ClassA_n")]int n)
    {
        _message = "Message from constructor 2 of class A: " + n.ToString();
    }
}
```

The argument n is composed using ComposeExportedValue like:

```
container.ComposeExportedValue<int>("ClassA_n", 12);
```

Is there any way to update or remove/re-compose the value of n, say 20 instead of 12, in the same instance (container) of CompositionContainer?

Thanks

**Update:**
First off I am newbie in using MEF and I was trying to create a simple scenario for question. I might have oversimplified it and diverted from actual problem. Actually I have a factory class that gives me one of the exported classes based on specified type. The exported classes have a constructor argument of type, say ClassB.

```
public class ClassFactory 
{
    public T GetClassA<T>() where T : IClassA
    {
        return MEF.CurrentContainer.GetExportedValue<T>();
    }
}
public class ClassA : IClassA
{
    [ImportingConstructor]
    public ClassA(IClassB classB)
    {
    }
}
```

Now what I want is to tell the factory class whether to reuse the existing instance (that was imported previously) of ClassB for multiple calls or reset/create a new instance. I tried CreationPolicy.NonShared too, but couldn't figure out how to use that in my scenario. I don't want new instance all the time or for all classes, rather I want to control it.

Comment: I don't know how to solve this, but if I may offer a bit of advice, consider trying to think of two or three relevant tags to add to it, so that you might attract someone more familiar with the problem. :)

Comment: Thanks Augusta! However it doesn't allow me to add a new tag due to reputation level.

Comment: Is the intention to create a new instance every time when you call ComposeExportedValue() ?

Comment: @alexm, Please see the update to my question. I was trying to use ComposeExportedValue() but it may not be required.

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/q/5433444/340760

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @BrunoLM for the link but that solution works when you have Non-Shared export. Unfortunately I had Shared export.

The solution I found is to use the function CompositionContainer.Compose(CompositionBatch batch). CompositionBatch gives you more control on parts to export. You can reset any part by using CompositionBatch.RemovePart and then calling CompositionContainer.Compose again.